# Why do Chrome and Safari incorrectly render <rb> and <rt> in <ruby> tags?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari

MDN says that [`rb`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/rb) and [`<rt>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/rt) tags (which are used inside [`<ruby>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby) tags and most commonly used for East Asian languages) are supported in Chrome and Safari. However, MDN's example renders incorrectly in both. The following is the first example in the `<rb>` docs:

```html
<ruby>
  <rb>漢<rb>字
  <rp>(</rp><rt>kan<rt>ji<rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
```

### Firefox 78.0.2 ✅

[image: Firefox]

### Chrome 84.0.4147.105 ❌

[image: Chrome]

### Safari 13.1.2 ❌

[image: Safari]

### Questions

Is MDN just *wrong* here about Safari/Chrome support?

Or is the MDN example HTML snippet incorrect? (Chrome and Safari both incorrectly render various examples in this 2015 Mozilla Hacks blog post, ["Ruby support in Firefox Developer Edition 38"](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/ruby-support-in-firefox-developer-edition-38/).)

Note that `<ruby>` tags using just `<rt>` inside, and *without* `<rb>`, seem to render fine in both Chrome and Safari. The *second* example in the [`<rb>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/rb) MDN docs follows, and looks like the Firefox screenshot above in both other browsers:

```html
<ruby>
  漢 <rp>(</rp><rt>Kan</rt><rp>)</rp>
  字 <rp>(</rp><rt>ji</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
```

In the comments section of the 2015 [Mozilla blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/ruby-support-in-firefox-developer-edition-38/) above, the author mentions that `<rb>` is not supported by other browsers, could this still be true (despite MDN browser compatibility data)?

Comment: Opened an issue with the MDN BCD project: https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/6475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/rb) now shows `rb` as non-standard (since the spec marks it as [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)) and with incomplete support among browsers.

See discussion on the [Browser Compatibility Data issue](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/6475).